# Organization proxy self signed certificate not trusted in cent os VM

Tags: centos

I am having a VM created out of Cent OS 7.6 ISO. when I try to CURL https://xxxxxxx it shows "(60) CURl Peer certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user. This happens even after I downloaded the certificate and aded it to the store using update-ca-certificate command (ref: https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html). The only doubt I have is that the client system is behind my organization network proxy.
Is there any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: the issue caused by - missing a complete set of certificate of the org proxy. Now got both the certificates (there are two used in the org) applied and the issue is solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the issue caused by - missing a complete set of certificate of the org proxy. Now got both the certificates (there are two used in the org) applied and the issue is solved.